# Use a Macro or Formula to replace a single letter with a string of text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

This should be pretty simple. I want to use a formula or macro that will automatically replace a letter with a string of text within the same cell. Ex.: If I type the letter "r" in Cell A1 I want it to automatically replace it with "C123R" in cell A1. I want this to only apply to column A.

Comment: Sounds like you can use the `AutoCorrect Options` or the `Name Manager` to define names, while using the latter you can use a single letter but cant use letters like `r`, `R`,`c`, or `C` these falls under `Naming Rules. with the first one, you can click on `File` --> `Options` --> `Proofing` --> `AutoCorrect Options` --> `Replace` enter `r` --> `With` enter `C123R`. Using a formula you cant do it with a cell where some data already exists that is formula cant override a constant value, that needs `VBA` here.

Comment: How would I do it if I wanted to only apply to one column? Say I want to insert "51827" but I want to fast-key it as I will be putting this into hundreds of cells. I want this "fast-key" to only apply to one cell.

Comment: No, it will be all across the sheets/workbooks(**AutoCorrect Options/Defined Names**). Using `Excel Formula` you will need additional columns, now what I understand using `VBA` will be your best bet here, and I am not that much familiar with `VBA` so cant suggest on that. What you are asking for that you will enter `r` in cell `A1` and it will auto change to `C123R` requires `VBA` or the one I have suggested but as said above it will be all across, using formula have to enter the formula in someother cells. Definitely, `VBA` is the right approach here.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Value = "r" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = "C123R"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**N.B.** *In the above code Column number & Cell Count are adjustable.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want the replacement effect to be visible immediately when you edit, you can do so by defining the appropriate `AutoCorrect` option. The substitution is for the word `r` written in lowercase or uppercase. `Word` means that the `r` must be separated from other parts of the text by a space or punctuation mark.
The code includes several procedures placed in different modules:
In the standard module:

```
Public Auto As Boolean

Sub Adjust(Auto As Boolean)
   Dim item As String: item = "r"
   Dim repl As String: repl = "C123R"
   If Auto Then
      Application.AutoCorrect.AddReplacement item, repl
   Else
      On Error Resume Next
      Dim ACR: ACR = Application.AutoCorrect.ReplacementList
      repl = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, ACR, 2, False)
      If Err Then Exit Sub  ' not defined
      On Error GoTo 0
      Application.AutoCorrect.DeleteReplacement item
   End If
End Sub
```

In the sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   On Error Resume Next
   Set Target = Intersect(Target, Columns(1))
   On Error GoTo 0
   Adjust Not Target Is Nothing
End Sub
```

In the Thisworkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
   Adjust True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   Adjust False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
   Adjust False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Adjust True
End Sub
```

If you want to replace `r` in a cell after you commit it, you can use the macro shown in another response, or you can use the `Find/Replace` function that can be possibly also saved as a macro.